# SQL Query that works in MySQL but not from Java

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jdbc, sql-insert

I have a multiple INSERT INTO query

```
Connection con = null;

String sql = "START TRANSACTION;"
               + "Set autocommit=0;"
               + " INSERT INTO CARS (CARNR) VALUES (" + (getLetzteFahrzeugNr() +1)+ ");"
               + " INSERT INTO KAUFINFO (CARNR) VALUES (" + (getLetzteFahrzeugNr() +1)+ ");"
               + " INSERT INTO POSITIONS (CARNR) VALUES (" + (getLetzteFahrzeugNr() +1)+ ");"
               + " COMMIT;";

System.out.println(sql);           
Statement stmt = null;
ResultSet rs = null;


Integer carnr = null;
stmt = con.createStatement();
stmt.executeUpdate(sql);
```

although that the query is working perfectly at the MySQL directly but when I call it from the Java code doesn't working and all the time I m receiving the Error.

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Set autocommit=0; INSERT INTO CARS (CARNR) VALUES (108); INSERT INTO KAUFINFO (C' at line 1
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:386)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1052)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4098)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4030)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2490)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2651)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2671)
at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeUpdate(StatementImpl.java:1749)
at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeUpdate(StatementImpl.java:1666)
at util.DbUtilities.getNewFahrzeugNr(DbUtilities.java:131)
at util.DbUtilities.main(DbUtilities.java:231)
```

for my research have seen that for an INSERT INTO have to use executeUpdate, before I had it executequery .

Comment: This is not one query but several ones; moreover some of them are not even queries but MySQL specific commands. So, obviously, this kind of query cannot be run from JDBC.

Comment: but when I call it the query to the MySql is working , should I do it seperately ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `;` is used to separate several statements. When using JDBC, you need to execute each of them separately:

```
Connection con = ...;
con.setAutoCommit(false);

Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
stmt.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO CARS (CARNR) VALUES (" + (getLetzteFahrzeugNr() +1)+ ")");
stmt.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO KAUFINFO (CARNR) VALUES (" + (getLetzteFahrzeugNr() +1)+ ")");
stmt.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO POSITIONS (CARNR) VALUES (" + (getLetzteFahrzeugNr() +1)+ ")");

con.commit();
```

Mandatory comment:
Using a [`PreparedStatement`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html) would probably be neater, and more secure.